# Debian package (.deb) that only installs from source

Tags: ubuntu, package, debian, packaging, deb

I have a C++ application that I want to deploy to Ubuntu/Debian users.  But I have one constraint: this application **should not be pre-compiled binary**, but must compile in user environment. How can I organize the source `.deb` package that will be builds on user machine ?

Steps:

1. Run `tar -czf project_1.0.orig.tar.gz project-1.0` to get `.orig` tarball
2. Run `dh_make` to get `debian` folder
3. Update `debian/control` and `debian/rules` files
4. Run `dpkg-source -b` to get `.dsc` and `.debian.tar.xz`
5. **What should I do to get `.deb` file ???**

```
|-- project-1.0
|   |-- debian
|   |   |-- changelog
|   |   |-- control
|   |   |-- copyright
|   |   |-- rules
|   |   `-- source
|   `-- src
|       |-- CMakeLists.txt
|       `-- main.cpp
|-- project_1.0-1.debian.tar.xz
|-- project_1.0-1.dsc
`-- project_1.0.orig.tar.gz
```

***debian/control***

```
Source: project
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Maintainer: My Name <my.mail@example.com>
Build-Depends:  cmake, debhelper-compat (= 12), qtbase5-dev, qtdeclarative5-dev
Standards-Version: 4.5.0

Package: project
Architecture: any
Multi-Arch: foreign
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${shlibs:Depends}, qml-module-qtquick2
Description: Super usefull tool
```

***debian/rules***

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- -DIS_DEV=OFF
```

**Thank a lot in advance !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sane way to create a Debian package with these requirements. Just make sure installing from source works out of the box on your target platform(s).

You might want to ensure that any dependencies are installed, perhaps as part of your `Makefile`.  This serves the same purpose as having a sequence of `Build-Depends:` in your `debian/control` file.